# ASP Page opens XML file on shared folder but ONLY AS ANONYMOUS

Tags: asp.net, xml, permissions, ado

This code opens XML file fine unless I UNCOMMENT the code to force login. Then I get:

> "Error 3709:The connection cannot be used to perform this operation. It is either closed or invalid in this context."

Why can I only open anonymously?

```
<%Option Explicit%>
<%Response.Buffer=True%>
<%Server.ScriptTimeOut=120%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--METADATA
TYPE="TypeLib"
NAME="Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 2.8 Library"
UUID="{2A75196C-D9EB-4129-B803-931327F72D5C}"
VERSION="2.8"
-->

<%
Dim sUserName, rsXML
Const LoadsDB="\\fs1\FileCache\EZL_GridLoads.xml"

'If sUserName="" Then
'  ' Force login if we are anonymous
'  If Request.ServerVariables("LOGON_USER") = "" Then
'    Response.Status = "401 Access Denied"
'    Response.End
'  End If
'End If

Response.Write "User=" & Request.ServerVariables("LOGON_USER") & "<br/>"

On Error Resume Next
Set rsXML=Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
rsXML.Open LoadsDB,,,,adCmdText

if err.number then
  response.write "Error " & Err.Number & ":" & Err.Description & "<br/>"
  response.write "Opening XML file"
  response.end
else
  Response.Write "XML successfully opened!<br/>"
  Response.Write rsXML.RecordCount & " Records read.<br/>"
  rsXML.Close
end if

Set rsXML=Nothing
%>
```